# iOS remove faces and vertices from .obj file

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, scenekit

I use SceneKit to display .obj file. But to get an .obj file I use SDK from a sensor, so this sensor scans the arm of a man and returns the .obj file as a result. But when I load the .obj file, there are a lot of not proper parts (part of chair, part of the surface and so on), I need to remove these parts of the object, so as a result I has to see only the arm of the man.

So for example I want to select a rectangle or a sphere and to remove all vertices and faces in this sphere.

Are there any SDK or frameworks in iOS to do that?

P.S. I tried [nineveh](http://nineveh.gl/docs/tutorials/) and some other frameworks, but they can only view objects, they can't edit them.

**Edit**

I found the code to manipulate vertices (it merges vertices from different child nodes) in SceneKit. **Can I use the same approach to find vertices I need to remove (that are inside my rectangle) or it will be very slow with 65 K vertices?**

```js
//
//  VertexManager.m
//  Test
//

#import "VertexManager.h"
#import <SceneKit/SceneKit.h>
#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>

@implementation VertexManager

+ (SCNNode *) flattenNodeHierarchy:(SCNNode *) input
{
    SCNNode *result = [SCNNode node];
    
    NSUInteger nodeCount = [[input childNodes] count];
    if(nodeCount > 0){
        SCNNode *node = [[input childNodes] objectAtIndex:0];
        
        NSArray *vertexArray = [node.geometry geometrySourcesForSemantic:SCNGeometrySourceSemanticVertex];
        SCNGeometrySource *vertex = [vertexArray objectAtIndex:0];
        
        SCNGeometryElement *element = [node.geometry geometryElementAtIndex:0]; //todo: support multiple elements
        NSUInteger primitiveCount = element.primitiveCount;
        NSUInteger newPrimitiveCount = primitiveCount * nodeCount;
        size_t elementBufferLength = newPrimitiveCount * 3 * sizeof(int); //nTriangle x 3 vertex * size of int
        int* elementBuffer = (int*)malloc(elementBufferLength);
        
        /* simple case: here we consider that all the objects to flatten are the same
         In the regular case we should iterate on every geometry and accumulate the number of vertex/triangles etc...*/
        
        NSUInteger vertexCount = [vertex vectorCount];
        NSUInteger newVertexCount = vertexCount * nodeCount;
        
        SCNVector3 *newVertex = malloc(sizeof(SCNVector3) * newVertexCount);
        SCNVector3 *newNormal = malloc(sizeof(SCNVector3) * newVertexCount); //assume same number of normal/vertex
        
        //fill
        NSUInteger vertexFillIndex = 0;
        NSUInteger primitiveFillIndex = 0;
        for(NSUInteger index=0; index< nodeCount; index++){
            
            @autoreleasepool {
                node = [[input childNodes] objectAtIndex:index];
                
                NSArray *vertexArray = [node.geometry geometrySourcesForSemantic:SCNGeometrySourceSemanticVertex];
                NSArray *normalArray = [node.geometry geometrySourcesForSemantic:SCNGeometrySourceSemanticNormal];
                SCNGeometrySource *vertex = [vertexArray objectAtIndex:0];
                SCNGeometrySource *normals = [normalArray objectAtIndex:0];
                
                if([vertex bytesPerComponent] != sizeof(float)){
                    NSLog(@"todo: support other byte per component");
                    continue;
                }
                
                float *vertexBuffer = (float *)[[vertex data] bytes];
                float *normalBuffer = (float *)[[normals data] bytes];
                
                SCNMatrix4 t = [node transform];
                GLKMatrix4 matrix = MyGLKMatrix4FromCATransform3D(t);
                
                //append source
                for(NSUInteger vIndex = 0; vIndex < vertexCount; vIndex++, vertexFillIndex++){
                    GLKVector3 v = GLKVector3Make(vertexBuffer[vIndex * 3], vertexBuffer[vIndex * 3+1], vertexBuffer[vIndex * 3 + 2]);
                    GLKVector3 n = GLKVector3Make(normalBuffer[vIndex * 3], normalBuffer[vIndex * 3+1], normalBuffer[vIndex * 3 + 2]);
                    
                    //transform
                    v = GLKMatrix4MultiplyVector3WithTranslation(matrix, v);
                    n = GLKMatrix4MultiplyVector3(matrix, n);
                    
                    newVertex[vertexFillIndex] = SCNVector3Make(v.x, v.y, v.z);
                    newNormal[vertexFillIndex] = SCNVector3Make(n.x, n.y, n.z);
                }
                
                //append elements
                //here we assume that all elements are SCNGeometryPrimitiveTypeTriangles
                SCNGeometryElement *element = [node.geometry geometryElementAtIndex:0];
                const void *inputPrimitive = [element.data bytes];
                size_t bpi = element.bytesPerIndex;
                
                NSUInteger offset = index * vertexCount;
                
                for(NSUInteger pIndex = 0; pIndex < primitiveCount; pIndex++, primitiveFillIndex+=3){
                    elementBuffer[primitiveFillIndex] = offset + _getIndex(inputPrimitive, bpi, pIndex*3);
                    elementBuffer[primitiveFillIndex+1] = offset + _getIndex(inputPrimitive, bpi, pIndex*3+1);
                    elementBuffer[primitiveFillIndex+2] = offset + _getIndex(inputPrimitive, bpi, pIndex*3+2);
                }
            }

        }
        
        NSArray *sources = @[[SCNGeometrySource geometrySourceWithVertices:newVertex count:newVertexCount],
                             [SCNGeometrySource geometrySourceWithNormals:newNormal count:newVertexCount]];
        
        NSData *newElementData = [NSMutableData dataWithBytesNoCopy:elementBuffer length:elementBufferLength freeWhenDone:YES];
        NSArray *elements = @[[SCNGeometryElement geometryElementWithData:newElementData
                                                            primitiveType:SCNGeometryPrimitiveTypeTriangles
                                                           primitiveCount:newPrimitiveCount bytesPerIndex:sizeof(int)]];
        
        result.geometry = [SCNGeometry geometryWithSources:sources elements:elements];
        
        //cleanup
        free(newVertex);
        free(newNormal);
    }
    
    return result;
}

//helpers:
GLKMatrix4 MyGLKMatrix4FromCATransform3D(SCNMatrix4 transform) {
    GLKMatrix4 m = {{transform.m11, transform.m12, transform.m13, transform.m14,
        transform.m21, transform.m22, transform.m23, transform.m24,
        transform.m31, transform.m32, transform.m33, transform.m34,
        transform.m41, transform.m42, transform.m43, transform.m44}};
    return m;
}



GLKVector3 MySCNVector3ToGLKVector3(SCNVector3 vector) {
    GLKVector3 v = {{vector.x, vector.y, vector.z}};
    return v;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

No. You'll want to use a 3d tool like Blender, Maya, 3ds Max, or Cheetah 3D.

Comment: can you check the code I inserted in my answer. Will it be possible to do like that or will it be very slow ?